# Ruby string escape characters

Tags: ruby, string, escaping

I want to get the quoted string in the line below into a string exactly as-is, but I am tripping on the necessary escape sequences for Ruby.   `mycommand.cmd` is really a wrapper for powershell.exe so I want to preserve everything between the quotes, and hold onto the escape characters that are already there.

```
mycommand.cmd "^|foreach-object { \"{0}=={1}\" -f $_.Name, $_.Found }"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use single quotes :

```
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :001 > '^|foreach-object { \"{0}=={1}\" -f $.Name, $.Found }'
 => "^|foreach-object { \\\"{0}=={1}\\\" -f $.Name, $.Found }"
```

The only escape characters in single quotes are : `\'` and `\\`

Comment: You double escaped the quotes, was that intentional? If not just add a % in front.

Comment: @pguardiario Kassym didn't double-escape the quotes, Ruby did when it responded with a representation of the same string as a double-quoted string. They are equivalent.

Comment: Right. He didn't do it, ruby did. After he typed in the things that made ruby do that. Thanks for clearing that up ;)

Comment: i will accept that as answer.  i was doing this for something in puppet, but somewhere else through its processing is it not treating this properly.