# How to escape powershell command arguments when calling from Ruby/Chef?

Tags: ruby, powershell, chef-infra

I'm currently running into a bog-standard [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) problem, but the environment is Chef + Ruby + powershell.

All of the [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443375/how-to-escape-command-line-arguments-on-powershell) [I've seen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270944/ruby-string-escape-characters) so far appear inadequate: they surround the arguments with quotes, but do not fully escape the arguments.  [Shellwords](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html) and [shellescape](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html#method-c-shellescape) look promising, but they appear to be bash-specific.

For example, I may want to construct in Chef this windows shell command:

```
.\foo.exe BAR="#{node['baz']}"
```

Generalizing from the SQL dev world I'd naively anticipate an interface something like this:

```
cmd = "foo.exe BAR=?"
args = (node['baz'])
run-command(cmd, args)
```

Where `run-command` would handle escaping any arguments.  Instead I see interfaces that remind me of the bad old SQL days when developers had to construct SQL as a string, and escape any arguments "by hand".

Any pointers to best practices on how to proceed?  Use [system](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-system)?  Thanks!

**Edit:** to be clear, the argument `baz` above can be expected to include arbitrary text, including possibly any combination of characters.  Think of it as being identical to the [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) problem.

Comment: Most likely you don't need to try too hard. See if [this article](http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/running-executables-powershell) helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the link, @Bill_Stewart.  Unfortunately that article seems to deal entirely with spaces in arguments, and its solution is to enclose them in double quotes.

Comment: You can use the `showargs.exe` command-line utility in the download to see the actual command line that PowerShell constructs.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest generic solution is to use the array form for the `execute` resource's `command` property. This avoids all shell parsing an runs the command verbatim.

```
execute 'whatever' do
  command ['foo.exe', "BAR=#{node['baz']}"]
end
```

This doesn't work for `script` style resources though, which take a string for the script chunk to run, including `powershell_script`. There you would need something more tailored to PowerShell and I don't know its rules well enough to say if Shellwords would match.